# Christmas is over, the demon will soon arise

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> There's this little helpless creature that would fear,
>
> how Christmas is over and coming is a new year.
>
> For a demon horned creature would shortly arise,
>
> to take the little creature's home, despite its cries.

What are the two creatures?

Answer (score 3):

I think these two animals are most likely:

> A **RAT** and an **OX**.

*There's this little helpless creature that would fear,*
*how Christmas is over and coming is a new year.*

> In terms of physical size, a rat is a '*little creature*', and 2020 has been **the Year of the Rat** in the [Chinese Zodiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_zodiac). With the end of the year approaching, the rat's time is almost up...

*For a demon horned creature would shortly arise,*
*to take the little creature's home, despite its cries.*

> The coming of the new year will bring with it fairly soon - February 12th, in fact - the beginning of a new lunar year, and with that the start of the next year in the Chinese Zodiac cycle: **the Year of the Ox**. An ox has horns ('*demon horned*') and it will *take the little creature's home* in the sense that it will replace the rat as the symbol of the next year...

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> 2020 and 2021
>  New year will make 2021 take 2020s place .